# Create a Variable if it Does Not Exist Using Xarray mfdataset

Tags: python, python-xarray

I need to check if a variable exists in my data, if it doesn't exist I need it to be created in a preprocessing step.

```
path_list = '/media/william/PhD/DownloadRadiation/GFS/20200716/gfs*.grib2'

nan = float('nan')

def preprocessing(radi):
    if radi['dswrf'] not in radi:
        return radi.assign(dswrf=nan)

radi = xr.open_mfdataset(path_list, concat_dim='valid_time', preprocess=preprocessing, decode_times=False, combine='nested', engine='cfgrib',
                        backend_kwargs={'filter_by_keys':{'shortName': 'dswrf', 'typeOfLevel':'surface'},'indexpath':''})
```

Comment: Looks like you need to return radi if the condition is false… otherwise this should work? Are you getting an error? If so, please always include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback)

Comment: I am encountering error that the dswrf variable does not exist, but it does not exist in only one of the files, so I would like to do this check before, if the dswrf variable does not exist in a file, create it.

Comment: No I’m saying try to implement what you have (fix the function so it returns in both cases) and then if you’re still encountering an error, [edit] your question to include the ***full*** traceback